# Any drawbacks using this input validation method in JavaFX?

Tags: validation, javafx

Since there seem to be no methods for input validation in JavaFX, I was thinking about how to do it in a clean way in my current project.

Here is my idea:

1. All validation rules are regular expressions (like "min-length", "not-empty", "only-numbers", etc), which are stored in a .properties file
   Example: `validationrules_only_numbers="[0-9]+"`
2. I use this validations in the .fxml file by defining the `<properties>` tag for any input that should be validated
   Example:
   `<ChoiceBox><properties rules="%validationrules_only_numbers"/></ChoiceBox>`
3. In an abstract/parent controller I write a method which gets all children of the current AnchorPane and iterates over them (lets say after the user clicks OK to submit the form). All children which have validation rules are them passed to another method, which depending on the Type of the inputfield applies the validation rules to the input.
4. All controls with validation errors then get highlighted.

What I personally like about this idea:

- the validation rules are easily expandable by just adding them to the .properties file
- the rules are assigned in the .fxml file
- all the controllers (which extend the abstract/parent controller) dont need to perform any validation tasks

What I dont like/am unsure if it works good in reality:

- the validation rules are all regular expressions, I don't know if that works well with all the input fields (but I don't mind coding "hacks" to make it work, since I would do it only one time in a parent controller)
- I must check the controls with instanceof to apply the rule correctly for this specific control, since not all controls have a `getText()` method and the input needs to be validated in other ways
- don't know if there is a better way to put the rules in the .fxml file then using `<properties>`

What are your thoughts? Is there anything important I am missing here?

I was googling about this topic for several days and there seems to be no really good solution like those we are familiar with from the web development community.

Comment: As an aside, can you provide code example, or link to such, that shows how to get this `<properties>` back from the `Node`? I can't seem to find any documentation about it, and it seems interesting!

Comment: @sillyfly lets say you got a ChoiceBox like in my example above, then you could do `ObservableMap<Object, Object> controlProperties = choiceBox.getProperties();` and then `String rules = (String) controlProperties.get("rules");`

Comment: Thank you. Now all we need is for this to be added to Scene Builder:  https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8090540

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you re-invent the wheel you might want to have a look at the validation framework contained in the ControlsFX package. Maybe you can combine that with your ideas.

Comment: Thanks, i already stumbled upon ControlsFX, but the example seemed to be pretty bad so i didnt look close enough.Yea, from the point on where i already have the control-element, i can perfectly use the ControlsFX-Validation since i can pass a regex pattern to the methods and it also helps with decorating the controls in case of errors etc.So basically, only one part of the question is left, and that is if it is a good way to use `<properties>` to get the rule (=regex) for validation, like in the example above. I cant stop thining that this can be done better too.

Comment: To summarize whats left from my original question: where is the best place to save the regex's for validation and how to bind those to input elements? Originally i wanted to put the regex's in a properties file but i think now i would rather use an enum or constants. But no idea how to bind those to the input elements.